# Completely replace input type="button" with an icon

Tags: html, css

Here is the code. Of course, it needs to keep all the functionality. How could one achieve that?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 This is how it looks right now:
 <input type='button' value='+' class='qtt' field='quantity' />
  
<br /><br />

 This is how I want it to look:
  <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
```

Comment: You can simply use the `button` tag instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `button` tag and adjust its CSS as you like:

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that, but I guess I mistyped something and it didn't work. By the way, I'm going to also add `focus { outline: 0;` so it won't have that blue border when clicked, and also I will need to set background as white, because right now it has a grey one.

Comment: Yes, just override the default `button` design and it'll look great!

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus-square" style="font-size:30px"></i></button>
```